# How to save logins in a winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, authentication

I have a winform application and a list of logins to some web-service. Upon checking 'remember me' I serialize a dictionary into a file along with the encrypted password, but I wonder if this is the best practice to do such a thing or not..
Here's my code

```
public void LoginsInit()
{
  FileStream file = new FileStream(loginsFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
  try
  {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    loginsDictionary = (Dictionary<string, string>)formatter.Deserialize(file);
    string[] allusers = loginsDictionary.Keys.ToArray();
    int usersCount = allusers.Length;
    userNameTextBox.Text = allusers[usersCount - 1];
  }
  catch (SerializationException ex)
  {
    loginsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to open file: " + ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    file.Close();
  }
}

private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //LoginToService();
  string username;
  string password;
  username = serviceClientReference.UserLogin = userNameTextBox.Text;
  password = serviceClientReference.Password = EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(this.passwordTextBox.Text, EncryptDecrypt.c_strEncryptkey1, EncryptDecrypt.c_strEncryptkey2);

  if (rememberMe.Checked)
  {
    if (loginsDictionary.ContainsKey(username))
      loginsDictionary[username] = password;
    else
      loginsDictionary.Add(username, password);
  }
  FileStream file = new FileStream(loginsFilePath, FileMode.Create);
  try
  {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(file, loginsDictionary);
    file.Flush();
  }
  catch (SerializationException ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to open file: " + ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    file.Close();
  }

  string errorStr;
  int errorNo;
  try
  {
    bool res = serviceClientReference.EstablishConnection(out errorStr, out errorNo);
    if (!res)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(errorStr);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    Logger.Log(TraceLevel.Error, "", exception);
    MessageBox.Show("Fatal Error Unable to login to MU");
  }
}

private void usernameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (loginsDictionary.ContainsKey(userNameTextBox.Text))
    passwordTextBox.Text = EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(loginsDictionary[userNameTextBox.Text], EncryptDecrypt.c_strEncryptkey1, EncryptDecrypt.c_strEncryptkey2);
}
```

Comment: Is the remember me functionality good over time(application close and reopen) or is just for the current insance of the application?

Comment: it's good over time. the LoginsInit() is called at intance construction time to instantiate the dictoinary from the saved file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to preserve user specific **Settings** across application instances then you should check the [Application Settings Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx) that is built into .NET.  That gives you persisting and reloading capabilities (some configuration required).  There is also [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.aspx) for additional security and features.  Regardless of what you use continue to encrypt the Password.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using [DPAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/05/126825.aspx) to manage your keys.

Answer (score 0):

When managing sensitive information such as passwords, you better use the [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) Class
to store your credentials.